# Sigsegv upon running my play 1.2.4 application

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

The 'heroku logs' output is located here:

https://raw.github.com/gist/3118402/fc9e0617dee107d44ff5b07823b954fb8cd46c15/hrokuLogsOutput

I couldn't find very much information on sigsegv's when running play applications on heroku.  From the small info I could find, it seems there was something wrong with the JVM, but that heroku had fixed it.

I also don't really understand how to access the following report file within heroku to possibly give more information.

2012-07-15T12:33:26+00:00 app[web.1]: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
2012-07-15T12:33:26+00:00 app[web.1]: # /app/hs_err_pid3.log

What does the sigsegv mean in relation to running play applications?  What steps should I take to try and solve this problem?

Edit: I can't answer my own question for another 7 hours due to my lack of reputation.  Anyway, here it is

- So I tried both play 1.2.3 and 1.2.4, neither worked for me when running it on heroku.  The reason I didn't try 1.2.5 was because running 'play version' outputted  "play 1.2.x-localbuild".  I didn't trust this to be installed on heroku, even though 1.2.5 is an official release.

However, I just tried now and it worked fine.  Make sure the dependency is "play 1.2.5" and not "play 1.2.x-localbuild"

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried both play 1.2.3 and 1.2.4, neither worked for me when running it on heroku. The reason I didn't try 1.2.5 was because running 'play version' outputted "play 1.2.x-localbuild". I didn't trust this to be installed on heroku, even though 1.2.5 is an official release.
However, I just tried now and it worked fine. Make sure the dependency is "play 1.2.5" and not "play 1.2.x-localbuild"

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the JVM has crashed.  Unfortunately there isn't a way to access the saved dump file on Heroku.  But you should be able to reproduce the error by using the same version of OpenJDK 6 locally.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I run a windows environment and couldn't find openjdk 6 without spending a bunch of time getting it all configured.  If I start doing more consistent development while at home (not at work), then I'll probably dual boot my laptop with some form of Linux.

Thanks much for your help though James.  I see you're very active on the online play/heroku community and it's extremely appreciated.